# Loop through JSON data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
    "comments": [{
        "id": "1",
        "message": "Finish as soon as possible! Cibai!",
        "task_id": "1",
        "user_id": "1",
        "date_created": "2015-02-06 00:00:00.000000"
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "message": "Another message",
        "task_id": "1",
        "user_id": "1",
        "date_created": "2015-02-10 00:00:00.000000"
    }, {
        "id": "20",
        "message": "Comment about the header",
        "task_id": "1",
        "user_id": "1",
        "date_created": "2015-02-09 00:00:00.000000"
    }],
        "status": true
}
```

Here is my jQuery, problem is Iam getting null in the alert:

```
var ids = [];
$.each(e, function(i, item) {
    ids.push(item.id);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` property is part of the objects stored in the `comments` array. You need to loop over `e.comments` instead. Also, as you're building an array you can use `map()` instead of `each()`:

```
var ids = $.map(e.comments, function(item) {
    return item.id;
});
alert(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/btzctqb2/)